# CakePHP - making AJAX requests with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cakephp, xmlhttprequest

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and trying to populate a div with content using JavaScript AJAX request without jQuery. **The text from the request loads, but no JavaScript from that loaded file is triggered. I included another JavaScript file on that page, but it doesn't load either (checked network tab in Chrome)**. Why would this happen? I'm not getting any errors.

On Tests/testpage I make a POST request to another file which then populates the "content_container" div. The HTML loads, but none of the JavaScript does.

```
//tests/testspage.ctp

<div id = "content_container"></div>

<script>

 //remember, I'm doing this because I want to try it without jQuery
(function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("content_container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/tests/testpage_content",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
})();

</script>
```

The post request works fine and the div "content_container" is populated. However, none of the JavaScript on that page is triggered. **The file "another_js_file.js" doesn't load** (I checked the network tab). I can browse directly to it, so I know I have the correct path, no errors show.

Here's the content on testpage_content.ctp

```
//tests/testpage_content.ctp

<p>Your div now has content</p>


<script>

 window.onload = function() {
        alert("Content is loaded!");
    } 
</script>

<script src="/js/another_js_file.js"></script>
```

So to summarize, I open up /tests/testpage.ctp which makes an AJAX POST request to /tests/testpage_content.ctp. The div that I populate displays the text, but my JavaScript is not being triggered and another script that I include on that page is not loading. **What is causing the alert message not to show and "another_js_file.js" not to load?**

I checked the loading sequence in chrome developer tab and it shows

```
testpage
testpage_content
//another_js_file.js should appear here, but it does not
```

In my TestsController I just have

```
public function testpage(){



}


public function testpage_content(){

    $this->layout = 'ajax';

}
```

Comment: It is not supposed to, and it's not cake's fault but the way browsers work. Whatever you insert into the DOM with AJAX won't trigger scripts. You will need to parse and call the scripts in the results yourself through JS if you need to stick to that functionality.

Comment: @user221931 You should go ahead and make this an answer.

Comment: What about the extra script I included? Why won't that load? I tested it using jQuery POST just to see, and that script loads. Can you point me to something about parsing the scripts?

Answer (score 1):

the way that you importing your js file or css file is incorrect

Don't do this for your view

```
<script src="/js/another_js_file.js"></script>
```

try this for cake 2.X

```
echo $this->Html->script('another_js_file.js');
```

Comment: Does that do anything differently than just script tags?

Comment: yes. this helps and related to htaccess to give permission to your import files which also covers proper path for your import files.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in my comments, it is not supposed to load scripts, and it's not cake's fault but the way browsers work. Whatever you insert into the DOM with AJAX won't trigger scripts. You will need to parse and call the scripts in the results yourself through JS if you need to stick to that functionality.

With jQuery there are different methods you can do AJAX requests, some will just put the contents in the DOM or others that allow you to call functions later and do more staff with the data you got returned.

Comment: Right, well jQuery somehow loads external files placed in a file retrieved from an AJAX request, and that's what I want to do (load  another_js_file.js in my example above). What specifically should I search for to learn about this? I poked around the jQuery code but seeing as I don't understand the basics of this, I was having a tough time just looking through it.

Comment: I hope you didn't try to look at the minified version :) jQuery is heavily optimized and contaings lot's of tricks that make the code smaller but more difficult to understand.

Comment: LOL, no I didn't. I opened up the uncompressed version. It's still massive and lots of objects going on, so I was having trouble figuring out what was referencing what. So basically, if I wanted to be able to load another_js_file.js within that file I retrieved via the POST request, what are some keywords or topics I need to look up?

Comment: It's a simple as putting code on the appropriate callback function. In this case you want to do stuff after the AJAX request succeeds, so ``done()`` is the perfect point.